# How do I change the URL without causing Backbone to re-render the page?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone app.

In one area, there are subviews. These are correctly routed through from the Backbone router.

```
routes: { primary-view(/:subview): 'someFunction' }
```

So I end up with a URL like: `#/primary-view/subview`

I want to keep the URL up to date whenever a user clicks a menu item that changes the subview. These clicks are handled within the primary view so that the only part of the page that is re-rendered, when the user clicks one of these links, is the div containing the subview.

I have tried:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('#/primary-view/' + subview, {trigger: false});
```

And:

```
window.location.hash = '#/primary-view/' + subview;
```

But both of these cause the entire primary view to be re-rendered.

Comment: Y dont you make use events for the subview? and the click function can be handled without changing the url or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this can be achieved with [router.navigate](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate).

> Whenever you reach a point in your application that you'd like to save as a URL, call navigate in order to update the URL.

In your case you should **remove hash** from the URL

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/primary-view/' + subview, {trigger: false});
```

or

```
router.navigate('/primary-view/' + subview)
```

Comment: Router.navigate calls History.navigate, which I've already tried.